new template syntax: if(first) inside for is not working
I want to use the new @for syntax together with @empty to either show the user a table or some text telling there is no data.
With ngFor I usually checked the length of the data array. If not empty:

Add the table header
ngFor the data
Add the table footer

With the newer syntax I hoped to be able to combine those 3 steps above into the @for itself like this:
@for(order of licenseOverview.orders; track order.id; let firstRow = $first; let lastRow = $last) {
   @if(firstRow) {
       <table ...
   }

   <tr>
       <td>{{ order.reference }}</td>
       <td>{{ ... }}</td>
   </tr>

   @if(lastRow) {
       ... </table>
   }
}
@empty { <p>No data for you!</p> }

I expected this to just compile and render the table, but it seems like Angular can't handle this. Is there a way to get this to work?
EDIT: The error I get looks like this:
            @if(firstRow) {
                <table class="table table-responsive ds-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ 'Order' }}</th>
                            <th>{{ 'Expected On' }}</th>
                            <th>{{ 'Status' }}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            } ---> Unexpected closing block


We can use @empty to return just a single row along with a td tag with the value "No Results Found", working example below!
Code is almost the same, but the table must follow a particular syntax, where the table is at the top of loop, then followed by tbody(optional), then we should use the @for to loop through the rows one by one and add them, when no results found, we add a single row with a td with no results found. We can use CSS to make the table more presentable, but overall this is the approach to take!
Also due to the misformed table structure the for loop and $first didn't work, else it works great!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <table>
    <tbody>
      @for(order of licenseOverview.orders; track order.id; let firstRow = $first;
      let lastRow = $last) { 
        @if(firstRow) {
          <tr>
            <td>Reference</td>
            <td>Something</td>
          </tr>
        }
        <tr>
          <td>{{ order.reference }}</td>
          <td>{{ '...' }}</td>
        </tr>
        @if(lastRow) {
        <tr>
          <td>Reference</td>
          <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        } 
      } @empty {
        <tr>
          <td>No Results Found!</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  licenseOverview: any = {
    orders: [
      { id: 1, reference: 'test' },
      { id: 2, reference: 'test' },
      { id: 3, reference: 'test' },
      { id: 4, reference: 'test' },
      { id: 5, reference: 'test' },
    ],
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you for your answer. So if I understand you correctly, it is not possible to conditionally render the table header and footer using the $first and $last variables of the @for?

@rutgerm no, $first and $last work fine as seem in my stackblitz, I am saying you are getting the problem, because the table needs to be structured in a certain way, where we loop through the rows one by one, and not repeat the table element which was the problem in your code! if we move the table outside the for loop we do not get the error, again the point I want to highlight is that, the opening tag and closing tags are conditionally rendered, so angular compiler is complaining that there are incomplete tags! because there is no guarantee that the html is valid!

@rutgerm "it is not possible to conditionally render the table header and footer using the $first and $last variables of the @for" yes because the compiler does not understand it as valid HTML! due to conditional opening and closing tags!

That's too bad. I would assume that the $first and $last would definitely be rendered and therefore always lead to valid HTML. On the other hand, I do understand that this is very hard to support from a development point of view.
